# .net c# order management library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the need for sql based library that will allow me to create products, order items, orders, etc to support e-commerce on a .net mvc site. Does anybody have a suggestion as to where I can purchase a library like this or should I write it myself?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You know you can upvote the correct answer if you really, really like it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help start you off if you're stuck with getting started with your database schema, it's a library of free database models:

> [Library of Free Data Models from DatabaseAnswers.org](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/)

There's even a sample [Orders and Shipping model](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/e_commerce/index.htm) you could start off with.

I'd then suggest starting off with tool such as SubSonic or Linq to SQL to build your data access widgets:

> [SubSonic Project](http://www.subsonicproject.com/)

Comment: DatabaseAnswers is what I'm looking for. The schema below will save me a lot of time. Thanks

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/customers_and_campaigns_and_ecommerce/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need a library for this. Since you are not using an open source shopping cart there must be some need for a custom solution. Therefore you should design the tables yourself based on the needs. You can then create Stored Procedures that you call from within your .net code to update the data within the tables. This is pretty trivial and I doubt you need a specific library to accomplish this.

Comment: A shopping cart library doesn't quite fit my needs and contains a lot of complexity that is not required. I plan to write a basic library myself but the funcitonlaity seems so common that I wanted to if anybody knows of a simple open source library.